# Mean centering and average marginal effects

Tags: regression

I was reading Wooldridge's "Introductory Econometrics," in which he said:

"The centering of explanatory variables about their sample averages before creating quadratics or interactions forces the coefficient on the levels to be average partial effects.​" (p.180).

I am struggling to see why this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Once you center IV's (independent variables) the interpretation of a model is different. Particularly, if the data is centered with its average, then all the data is shifted by its average (subtracted by the average of the data) and the interpretation of any coefficients of the variables that were centered given by say a regression model, is interpreted to be the average of whatever it is the data is about, and this change in interpretation is also reflected in the interaction terms.

Comment: The question is about *average partial effects.*  Could you clarify how this answer addresses that?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm still a little bit confused about why the coefficients  give average partial effects. Could you give an example and maybe mathematical explanation?